# Due Dates of Expiry Progress Bar

Tags: google-apps-script, gsheets

I'm trying to create a progress bar for due dates of expiry in column D , but may coding not works , it show a numerical with decimal places .

someone helps me to show the progress bar with percentage or status like , "GOOD" , "SLIGHTLY GOOD" , "NOT GOOD" .

```
function updateProgress() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var dueDates = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues(); // Assuming due dates start from row 2 in column A
  var progressBars = [];

  var today = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < dueDates.length; i++) {
    var dueDate = new Date(dueDates[i][0]);
    var timeDiff = dueDate.getTime() - today.getTime();
    var daysDiff = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // Calculating the difference in days

    // Progress calculation based on due date proximity
    var progress = (daysDiff <= 0) ? 100 : Math.max(0, (100 - (daysDiff / 30) * 100)); // Assuming 30 days as the full duration

    progressBars.push([progress]);
  }

  // Update the progress bars in the sheet
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, progressBars.length, 1).setValues(progressBars);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I understand you are trying to create a progress bar. May I ask what are the criteria of each status on your progress bar? Also can you share a minimum reproducible sample of your sheet.

Comment: What is your progress bar supposed to look like?

Comment: Hi @Cooper , just like an battery percentage . but the status base on the color 

Green - "Good"
Yellow - "Slightly Good"
Red - "Not Good"

Comment: Hi @Babanana , just like an battery percentage . but the status base on the color Green - "Good" Yellow - "Slightly Good" Red - "Not Good"

Comment: What is your battery percentage bar supposed to look like

Comment: @Cooper , just like if the status is 80-100 % - "GOOD" (GREEN)
40-70 % - "SLIGHTLY GOOD" (YELLOW GREEN)
1-30 % - "NOT GOOD" ("RED")

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I  am still trying to understand where you can get the full duration? or How can I get the variables on your code based on your data. If also possible please include a copy of your Sheet so the community will have the ability to test the solutions.

Comment: @Babanana here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rUCu4_QM7tNXr94jELCLex2tWMuG5Rw6c_vHKI2DLOI/edit#gid=836191022

Comment: You can use conditional formating

Comment: I would just assume that it is 30 days for the full duration, also please allow access to public with your Google Sheet so that community can access it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Creating Progress Bar based on the Current Percentage from Full Duration:

I have created a simple Apps Script that will satisfy your requirement. Take note that this will be the basic steps on taking it. You can improve the script as you wish if you have more details you want to add. I created 2 Functions to dissect your requirements. First Part is getting from the Sheet and using the formula `Math.round((calculateDateDifferenceInDays(today, values[i][1]) / 30) \* 100)` to compute for the percentage of the days based off the full duration. The second function is to compute for days. As you can see with the if statements I also assume that you might encounter Non Number Inputs, Blanks I also took the liberty of assuming they have to be skipped.

### Code:

```
function processSheets() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Change depending on your Sheet Name.
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var progressBar = [];
  var today = new Date();
   for (i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
    if (Math.round((calculateDateDifferenceInDays(today, values[i][1]) / 30) * 100) >= 80) { 
      progressBar.push(["Good"])
    }
    else if (Math.round((calculateDateDifferenceInDays(today, values[i][1]) / 30) * 100) >= 40) {
      progressBar.push(["Slightly Good"])
    }
    else if (Math.round((calculateDateDifferenceInDays(today, values[i][1]) / 30) * 100) >= 1) {
      progressBar.push(["Not Good"]);
    }
    else{
      progressBar.push([" "])
    }
 }
sheet.getRange(2,4, progressBar.length, 1).setValues(progressBar)
}
function calculateDateDifferenceInDays(dateString1, dateString2) {
  const date1 = new Date(dateString1);
  const date2 = new Date(dateString2);
  const differenceInMs = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
  const differenceInDays = Math.floor(differenceInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return differenceInDays;
}
```

### Sample Output:

[image]

### References:

[Math Round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Feel free to raise questions regarding the solution.

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)